# "Flagged Posts" preview behaves strangely after voting to close

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

Over at `/tools/flagged/?subtype=close` I have seen some odd behaviour while reviewing posts.

Initially the post looks like this:

> [image]

I press Close Question and vote to close. Then it looks like this:

> [image]

Note that the "flag or disagree" button is sticking out oddly.

Now I press the disclosure triangle on the left, and get this:

> [image]

which looks fine. But when I close it up again by pressing the disclosure triangle, this results:

> [image]

which looks kind of like the pre-close state, only the "flag" button is in the wrong place.

I'm using Firefox 19 on Mac OS X.

Comment: I've noticed this some time ago. Personally I usually just ignore it and move on, as it doesn't hurt the functionality of the site (only the look of one very restricted page), but it probably does need to be addressed at some point.