# Expanding a closed question in 10k-Tools moves menu on right side to bottom

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, design, 10k-tools

I have noticed a layout issue in the 10k-Tools that stretches the posts horizontal and moves the menu from the right side to the bottom of the page (see Image). I reproduces it twice, but i´m currently stuck cause it involves closing a question and there aren´t any question to close at the moment.

I will try to reproduce it later and provide the steps here. Maybe someone else can reproduce it.

What I have done is that I flagged some answers and voted to close questions. I expanded the questions before i voted to close it.

**Update:**
Now i have reproduced the behavior.

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged
2. Find a question with Close Votes
3. Expand the question
4. Vote to close question
5. Collapse the question
6. Expand the question -> results in that the right menu moves to bottom. Collapsing the question moves menu back to the right side.

Browser: Chrome 28.0.1500.95

I have increased the Zoom Level to take the screenshot. The menu is also displayed at the bottom with 100 % Zoom.

[image]

Comment: You have [zoom-zoom](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DvbO6-k_SM) mode turned on your browser. Can you still reproduce this problem with the page at normal size (100%)?

Comment: @CodyGray i have only increased the zoom level to take the screenshot.

Comment: @CodyGray i have reproduced the behavior and updated my question with the required steps

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Flagged Posts" preview behaves strangely after voting to close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172398/flagged-posts-preview-behaves-strangely-after-voting-to-close)